# LDO Regulator ADP3338

Tags: ldo

I was looking the ADP3338 LDO Regulator of Analog Devices and i'm wondering whats the output voltage of this LDO?
http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADP3338.pdf

Is the output voltage same of input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the output voltage same of input?

What would be the point of that?

The answer to your question is:  It depends which ADP3338 you get - they come in a range of output voltages from 1.5V right up to 5V.  See the table on page 13 of the datasheet.